# Android Studio Layout: Trying to make button 50% width and 50% height, with button in center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I am working in Android Studio and want my layout to be a 2 by 2 grid of buttons with a button in the center.  See code below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/incentivebutton">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Incentive"
    android:id="@+id/incentiveButton"
    android:onClick="IncentiveButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:background = "@drawable/roundbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="55dp"
    android:paddingBottom="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCollect1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCollect3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCollect2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeAEh.png)

I like this layout, but I want the buttons to be 50% the height.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for design like this

[image]

You could use a `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/instagram"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have used `LinearLayout` with `weightSum`. See if it helps!